Nodemon Throwing Errors and Can't Find File
I'm very new to Node.js, Nodemon as a whole, and I've haven't used Javascript in a while. I'm making a Discord bot that send a quote from and array at a certain interval. I put the quotes in a separate file. I put the Here what the code looks like:
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const quotes = require('./quotes');
let currentIndex = 0; // Starts at the first quote


// Create a new Client object
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    ]
});

// The function to send a quote
function sendNextQuote() {
    
    const quote = quotes[currentIndex];
    var testChannel = client.channels.cache.get('*-channel id-*');
    if (channel) {
        channel.send(quote);
    }

    // Move to the next index and reset if need be
    currentIndex++;
    if(currentIndex >= quotes.length) {
        currentIndex = 0; // Loop back to the start
    }
}

client.on('ready', (c) => {
    console.log(`${c.user.tag} is online.`);

   setInterval(sendNextQuote, 20*1000);
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);


Here's the error that I'm getting in the terminal:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1228
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '.quotes'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\gabsa\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Snapcube-Bot\src\index.js


What can I do? Also sorry for the weird formatting, it's my first post.
I've made sure that nodemon, and node.js is installed.
I made sure to use 'module.exports = quotes;' in the quotes file.

how do you run nodemon ? i mean through vs code or command line ?

can you check where this file path import  correctly or not : ".quotes"
